# Error trying to pass variable to make a report in Excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, report, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to pass the variable ***cat*** to search the data related in DB and make a report in excel.

Unfortunely i'm getting the following error:

[Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #1 [  $cat ]] in class ***movieController***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ca5x.png)

> Route:

```
Route::get('/search/report{cat}', [movieController::class , 'export'])->name('search-report');
```

> movieCatExport:

```
class movieCatExport implements FromCollection, Responsable, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize{
    use Exportable;
    //private $fileName='usertest.csv';
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */

   

    public function collection(){     
        $cat=$this->cat; 
        $film=film::with('category')->wherehas('category', function($q) use($cat){
            $q->where('name', $cat);
              })->join('semantic', 'semantic.idtable_record','=','film.film_id')
->join('language', 'language.language_id','=','film.language_id')->GET();
    
            return $film;
    }
  
    public function headings(): array{
        return [
            'title',
            'description',
            'year',
            'duration(min.)',
            'language',
            'features',
            'onto',
            'class',
            'proprierty'
                
            ];
        }
```

> movieController:

```
class movieController extends Controller{
    protected $table='film';
    private $excel;
    private $cat;
   
    public function __construct(Excel $excel, $cat){
        $this->excel =$excel;
        $this->cat=$cat;
    }    

    public function export(Excel $excel,string $cat){
            return $this->excel->download(new movieCatExport($cat), 'test.csv');
    }
}
```

**NOTE:Removed the __construct function and the following error appeared:**

Call to a member function download() on null

```
public function export(Excel $excel,string $cat){

            return $this->excel->download(new movieCatExport($cat), 'test.csv');

    }
```

NOTE2:I change from *$this->excel* to *$excel->download*
NOTE3:I figured it out that the collection is not receiving the $cat, now i need to solve that

Comment: What is $cat reference? is it a model?

Comment: Shouldn't your route be `/search/report/{cat}`? You're missing a `/` there.

Comment: @A.Seddighi when i press the report button it send the variable category($cat) to make the report

Comment: @TimLewis unfortunately the error remains

Comment: Ah, I think you just need to remove your `__construct()` method from `movieController`; it's likely that Route parameters, like `$cat`, aren't passed to the Constructor.  Combine that with adding the `/{cat}` in your Route should work.

Comment: @TimLewis now i'm getting the following error: Call to a member function download() on null

Comment: Oh cause `$this->excel` is set by that. It would be `return $excel->download(...);` with `__construct()` removed.

Comment: @TimLewis now the report only comes with the Headings(Title, desciption...) and no values

Comment: Sounds like your `collection()` method in `movieCatExport` is returning nothing. Your immediate issue has been solved, you'll have to debug your new issue on your own for a bit, and if you run into issues, open a new question.

Comment: @TimLewis i have already found that the function collection is not receiving the $cat.Now i need the find why

Comment: Because your `movieCatExport` has no `__construct($cat)` function, and `$this->cat` is never defined? Remember, each class has it's own `__construct()` method; the `movieController` had `$this->cat`, via that, but `movieCatExport` doesn't (at least according to the code you posted)

Comment: Thanks, already solved the problem.@TimLewis

Answer (score 0):

You should Specify what type `$cat` is in your controller

When it is a **string**

```
public function __construct(Excel $excel, string $cat){
    $this->excel = $excel;
    $this->cat = $cat;
}
```

Or when it's a **Model**:

```
public function __construct(Excel $excel, Cat $cat){
    $this->excel = $excel;
    $this->cat = $cat;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work

Comment: Is it specified in your `__construct()` and also an `export()` method?